# What would become of the earth's orbit if half of the sun's mass were suddenly to disappear?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I shall assume that the sun is at rest, so before the half mass disappear, the orbit of earth is an ellipse.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a [hypothetical *What if ________ happened*](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) question.

Comment: @KyleKanos I don't know, I think it's an interesting question that can provide insight into conservation of energy. I don't know what the rules are on physics exchange, though.

Comment: I request this question not to be closed because it involves mainstream physics and enhances the intuitive understanding of the dynamics of orbiting bodies

Comment: @brucesmitherson: who says it isn't mainstream? Aside from the fact that this type of question is *explicitly* categorized in the "don't ask" page, the question shows zero effort from OP to understand what would happen, so it could be closed as a zero-effort homework question. This type of question is a disaster for this site, IMO.

Comment: @KyleKanos Ok, I had a different position, and was not aware of the disaster this kind of questions produces. I agree, we must stick to the rules.

Comment: Related video: [What If the Sun Disappeared Right Now?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAjDtCuOHrA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer

Earth will escape from the solar system
(It no longer in a)

## Reason

IF you remember the Virial Theorem in order for a planet to have an orbit the average potential energy and average kinetic energy of a planet must have a relationship of
$$ 2K_{avg} = -U_{avg}$$

Where $U$ is a gravitational potential energy, which is given by
$$U_{avg} = -G\frac{M_{\text{sun}}m_{\text{planet}}}{R_{\text{planet}}}$$

If you reduce the mass of the sun by a half, potential energy will be half too.

Thus, now,
$$ 2K_{avg} > -\frac{1}{2}U_{avg}=-U_{avg,new}$$

In such case, the velocity of the planet is the **escape velocity**
of the new sun. The planet will fly away from the sun to somewhere else and becomes a massive interstellar junk.

Comment: So the orbit will be unbounded.

Comment: In short, Yes. Orbit will be unbounded by the Sun's gravitational field.

Comment: what is the minimum mass change required to reach escape velocity?  How does your argument change if, for instance, the change in mass is 1% instead of half?

Comment: @brucesmitherson Ok,orbit velocity **MUST** be an escape velocity at the radius that planet orbits (for circular orbit). Any slight change will, technically, blows earth away or pulls earth towards the sun. So in a Earth-Sun system **where anything else doesn't exist**, 1% change in mass of the Sun results in catastrophe.

Comment: do you mean that the circular orbit is "unstable" in the sense that any minimal perturbation will result in either escape or collapse?

Comment: Plus that seems wrong, see my answer

Comment: Hi Tom. It's a good answer and full marks for using the virial theorem to provide a simple elegant answer. One quibble though, doesn't the total energy change from $-K$ to zero when the mass of the Sun halves? After halving the mass $U$ changes from $-2K$ to $-K$ so the total energy is $K - K = 0$. That means the velocity of the planet is equal to the escape velocity not greater than it. The planet will head off in a parabolic orbit.

Comment: @JohnRennie give your trustability in this site, I wonder if you have the time or willingness to check my answer and point where it is wrong. If my answer is correct then this answer, comments included, is wrong

Comment: @brucesmitherson: your and Tom's answers are basically the same (subject to the point I mention above). It's just that using the virial theorem is a quick and easy way to get the answer.

Comment: @JohnRennie I disagree, the arguments, as he mentions in a comment, imply that any small variation (even 1%) in the mass will result in a escape velocity, which is incorrect.

Comment: But it is fine, wrong answer are voted up all the time

Comment: the virial theorem is irrelevant, the orbit can become an elongated ellipse such that $-U_{new,avg}=3K_{avg}$

Comment: @brucesmitherson I said given that solar system is made up only of Earth and Sun strictly, then 1% of change in mass will result in catastrophic event (in a distant future, may in 1*10^100 years later). If you Consider the conservation of energy it is obvious.
I don't think my answer is wrong. In a binary system orbit must follow the Virial theorem at the equilibrium according to `Carroll introduction to Astrophysics`

Comment: @brucesmitherrson Yes, the claim I've made 
__Ok,orbit velocity MUST be an escape velocity at the radius that planet orbits (for circular orbit). Any slight change will, technically, blows earth away or pulls earth towards the sun. So in a Earth-Sun system where anything else doesn't exist, 1% change in mass of the Sun results in catastrophe__ was wrong. But my answer to this question still holds correct I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This question have two approximate answers:

1. If sun mass decreased by half but suddenly then planet will pull out into interstellar space.
2. If mass of sun decreases slowly into half then planet orbit will be long elliptical because of sun weaker gravitational force.

Comment: I believe your 2nd point is incorrect.   The method of the drop in mass, slowly or quickly is irrelevant, earth's kinetic energy remains unchanged.   As the mass of the sun drops to below a certain point, the earth's kinetic energy is sufficient to escape.  Granted this ignores the chance that it might pass by another planet and get a gravitational assist in some other direction, perhaps slowing it down and keeping it in orbit.

Answer (score 0):

The detailed answer for elliptical orbits depends on the exact position along the orbit, so I will analyze the simpler case of an initial circular orbit.

The speed in a circular orbit is given by:

$v_{earth}=\sqrt{GM_{sun}/r_{earth}}$,

(where $r_{earth}$ is the distance to the sun, not the earth's radius) and the escape velocity by

$v_{e}=\sqrt{2GM_{sun}/r_{earth}}=\sqrt{2} v_{earth}$.

If you change the sun mass from $M$ to $pM$, where $p$ in the change-in-mass factor, you can calculate the new escape velocity, $ v'_{e}$:

$v'_{e}=\sqrt{2GpM_{sun}/r_{earth}}=\sqrt{2p} v_{earth}$.

You can notice that the escape velocity only becomes large enough to escape the sun if $p=1/2$: For such case 
$v'_{e}= v_{earth}$. That is, if the mass change is less that 50%, the orbit will remain bounded (will become elliptical),  a change in half will result in a parabolic orbit, and for larger changes (mass smaller than 50%) it will result in an hyperbolic orbit.