# Effect on orbit of Earth due to decreasing gravitational force of the Sun

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

What would happen to the motion of the earth, if the gravitational force of sun on earth starts decreasing uniformly with time?

What path would the earth follow?

**Note**
Consider Earth's orbit to be circular initially.

Comment: If (in the context of Newtonian Mechanics) the gravitational force of the sun started to decrease over time, the earth would leave the orbit and continue to fly farther away from the sun indefinetly. The exact path followed by earth depends on what you mean by "decreasing uniformly". Specifying that dependence would allow one to solve (perhaps numerically or after a suitable approximation) Newton's equation to get the path. How is this a doubt on gravitation?

Comment: By saying decreasing uniformly with time i mean that earth gravitational force suddenly is not becoming 0,it slowly becomes 0 ,so i think earth wouldnot just go tangentially in straight line leaving the circular motion,what path would it follow,would it be a spiral or something??

Comment: sorry,sun gravitation*

Comment: earth would want to increase its radius of circular motion when centripetal force(i.e,gravitational force of sun on earth) would decease to a particular value,will it go straight in line to the bigger apropriate circle or by following a curved path ??

Comment: Very much related? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221558/

Comment: What do you think would happen?  What equations connect the force of gravity from the sun to the motion of the earth?

Answer (score 1):

Because the Earth orbits the sun in a uniform circular path (in this problem), the gravitational force from the Sun acts as the Centripetal force on the Earth.  The Centripetal force pulling the Earth towards the Sun combined with Earth's own velocity produces a curved motion around the Sun.

To examine the effects of decreasing this gravitational / centripetal force, we have to use the basic formula for centripetal force.  Here it is:

Fc = mv^2 / r

In this formula, Fc has a direct-square relationship with velocity and an inverse relationship with r (which is the distance between the Earth and the Sun).  So, a decrease in Fc would either cause the Earth's velocity to decrease slightly or it would cause the distance to increase.

When you think about it, this makes sense.  A decrease in the Sun's pull of the Earth towards it would allow the Earth to "get free" a bit and move farther away.  At the same time, Earth's velocity would have to decrease slightly in order to not reach an escape velocity of the Sun's gravitational pull.  If there is less centripetal force pulling on the Earth, it would take less velocity for the Earth to fling out of orbit, so the Earth has to compensate for this.

The type of motion would remain the same though (assuming we started off with uniform circular motion).  Earth's orbit would still be circular around the sun, it would just be a larger circle and would go slightly slower in its orbit.